# Как лучше всего сделать общую операцию для всех методов контроллера в Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, mvc, cookie, servlet

Использую Spring Boot. Задача довольно простая - в каждом методе у меня однотипные операции, проверка, вошел ли пользователь, если не вошел кидаем его в одно место, иначе продолжаем, в случае ошибки ещё куда-то кидаем. Пока что я просто заключил это в отдельный метод, где делаются все проверки и вызывается переданная параметром функция. Но всё равно громоздко выглядит, куча одинаковых сигнатур методов, с перечнем одинаковых кук внутри:

```
public String method(
            @CookieValue(name = USER_ID_COOKIE_NAME, required = false) Cookie userId,
            @CookieValue(name = TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME, required = false) Cookie token) {
        return protectedAction(userId, token, user -> ...);
    }
```

То есть много таких методов получается. Я знаю есть и фильтры, и сервлеты, но что-то в голове не укладывается, как лучше всего сделать.

Или может не нужно никакого общего действия, может в спринге есть что-то поинтереснее для этих целей? Не я же первый, кто захотел достаточно активно с куками работать )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться аннотацией `@ModelAttribute` на методе. Тогда этот метод будет вызываться перед методами помеченными `@RequestMapping`. Вот пример

```
@ModelAttribute
public void populateModel(@RequestParam String number, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute(accountManager.findAccount(number));
}
```

В вашу модель будет добавлен новый атрибут.

Проверять залогинен ли пользователь лучше все используя Spring Security. Там вы можете прописать права на доступ к любой части вашего приложения.